# Why can't the Vision leave Westview?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In *WandaVision*, a female pre-S.W.O.R.D leader entered the Hex, and her body armor turned into a dress.

> When she was banished from the Hex, the dress came with her.

However, the Vision

> started to break down as soon as he tried to step outside of the Hex's boundary.

So why can a dress exist outside the Hex, but a robot can't?

Comment: Wasnt the dress still the armor, just modified. It still retained its bulletproof properties for example. The Vision on the other hand was created from nothing, so that would be the properties he had outside of the Hex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This Vision was created at the same time as the Hex and as is the same as with the boys he has been tied into its fabric. He simply cannot exist outside of it without breaking down. Agnes explains this briefly when talking about the boys.

> **Agnes:** Now, do you see? You tied your family to this twisted world, and now one can't exist without the other.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 9, “The Series Finale”</sub>

However, the body armour that Monica was wearing existed outside of the Hex and was only re-written upon entry to be the dress. That is why it can leave, it is not tied into the reality of the Hex but rather was altered to match it.

> **Monica:** Those pants are 87% Kevlar. It's not an illusion. Wanda is rewriting reality.
>
> **Darcy:** Permanently?
>
> **Monica:** If she can change things as they go into the Hex...
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 5, “On a Very Special Episode...”</sub>

Comment: So if she had stolen the Vision's corpse and thrown it in after the Hex created......

Comment: @Harry It depends upon the spell she casts. Remember White Vision was created from the Vision's body so presumably Wanda could have reanimated him similarly without the need for a Hex for him to live in.